# Problems with ActionBarSherlock themeing

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

In the application I am working with an `ActionBar Sherlock`. The error I am getting seems to be very strange as I am using the same theme for 2 other activities in the application.

**Manifest:**

```
        <activity
            android:name=".ABC"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/transTheme" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="com.example.ABC"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".XYZ"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/transTheme" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="com.example.XYZ"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".123"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/transTheme" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="com.example.123"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

**Style:**

```
<!-- Transparent Layout Themeing -->
<style name="transTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Translucent">
    <item name ="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name ="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name ="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
    <item name ="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

As in the manifest file, activities ABC and XYZ work without errors. I get my error in activity 123.

**Error Log:**

```
09-08 10:40:08.446: E/AndroidRuntime(23791): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-08 10:40:08.446: E/AndroidRuntime(23791): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.vaw.selfhelp/com.vaw.selfhelp.SureSMS}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You must use Theme.Sherlock, Theme.Sherlock.Light, Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar, or a derivative.
09-08 10:40:08.446: E/AndroidRuntime(23791):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
09-08 10:40:08.446: E/AndroidRuntime(23791):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
09-08 10:40:08.446: E/AndroidRuntime(23791):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
09-08 10:40:08.446: E/AndroidRuntime(23791):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
09-08 10:40:08.446: E/AndroidRuntime(23791):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-08 10:40:08.446: E/AndroidRuntime(23791):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
09-08 10:40:08.446: E/AndroidRuntime(23791):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
09-08 10:40:08.446: E/AndroidRuntime(23791):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-08 10:40:08.446: E/AndroidRuntime(23791):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-08 10:40:08.446: E/AndroidRuntime(23791):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
09-08 10:40:08.446: E/AndroidRuntime(23791):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
09-08 10:40:08.446: E/AndroidRuntime(23791):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-08 10:40:08.446: E/AndroidRuntime(23791): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You must use Theme.Sherlock, Theme.Sherlock.Light, Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar, or a derivative.
09-08 10:40:08.446: E/AndroidRuntime(23791):    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.generateLayout(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:1003)
09-08 10:40:08.446: E/AndroidRuntime(23791):    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.installDecor(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:915)
09-08 10:40:08.446: E/AndroidRuntime(23791):    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.setContentView(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:849)
09-08 10:40:08.446: E/AndroidRuntime(23791):    at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity.setContentView(SherlockActivity.java:229)
09-08 10:40:08.446: E/AndroidRuntime(23791):    at com.vaw.selfhelp.SureSMS.onCreate(SureSMS.java:29)
09-08 10:40:08.446: E/AndroidRuntime(23791):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-08 10:40:08.446: E/AndroidRuntime(23791):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
09-08 10:40:08.446: E/AndroidRuntime(23791):    ... 11 more
```

**SureSMS.java (or 123.java) line 29**

```
setContentView(R.layout.123layout);
```

I did try using the

```
setTheme(R.style.transTheme)
```

in the java class which got rid of the error but this didn't the activity its transparency. The application works fine for devices HoneyComb and above. I am only getting this error on devices below Android 3.0.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is you are not using the theme provided by ActionBarSherlock. You must use `Theme.Sherlock or Theme.Sherlock.Light or Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar` inorder to the action bar to work.

1. Option 1:

   You can remove all the  activity specific theming and add the theme to the application context.

   `<application
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock" >`
2. Option 2:

   You can change the

   `<activity
           android:name=".123"
           android:label="@string/app_name"
           android:theme="@style/transTheme" >`

   to

   `<activity
           android:name=".123"
           android:label="@string/app_name"
           android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock" >`
3. Option 3:

   You can use

   `<style name="transTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Sherlock">`

   instead of using the

   `<style name="transTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Translucent">`

Comment: i actually went with something similar to Option2 ... thank :)